# Writing in Blocks and receiving in blocks in stream object c#

Tags: c#, stream

I have two applications one on server and one on client.

On server side I write to stream like this.

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageSent);

stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

I am writing multiple string in stream one by one. The length of string is variable an reach max length of about 500

PROBLEM:

How to read on client side in blocks

What happen is sometimes I get combines string

Like I sent A,B,C

On client I received A, BC

I am client like this:

```
bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you've got a *stream* - just a sequence of bytes - but you're treating it as if it weren't a stream; as if it were a message-oriented protocol.

Fundamentally, with simple stream-based communications, there's nothing *inherent* to break the stream up into messages. If you want to do that, you need to build a layer on top. There are three common ways of doing this:

- Using an "end of message" token which you spot when reading
- Using a length-prefix before each message
- Using a sort of hybrid, where each message can consist of multiple blocks, each of which is length-prefixed, and a 0-length block representing "end of message"

The second of these is probably the simplest, but has the restriction that you need to know how large the message is before you start sending it. The third option gets round this by having a variable number of blocks. I would personally avoid the first option if possible - unless you have some natural "end of message" token which you would never, ever want to include as data *within* the message, you have to start working out an escaping scheme, which is a pain... and it's harder to read the data, too.

You don't have to do all of this from scratch, of course. If you've got .NET on both ends, you can use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` which support length-prefixed strings, and there are plenty of serialization frameworks around too, which typically handle this in some form or other. (My personal preference is Protocol Buffers, as it's efficient, platform-independent, and what I use at work. There are two common .NET ports - [one by myself](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port), and [one by Marc Gravell](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).)

Comment: when we say token it means any special symbol like '|' sign in the end and on the client split it in message or something else. I found such splitting like death of programming

Comment: @Moons: Yes, exactly. It's a pain in various ways - length-prefixing tends to be much nicer, if you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

As the name implies, what you're working with is a stream. There's no guarantee of a 1-1 correspondence between calls to `Write` on one side and calls to `Read` on the other.

One common way to send messages is to first send the message length (as say, an int converted to 4 bytes) and then the message.

Then (on the receiving side), read that length, (if needed) allocate a buffer of that size, and then make repeated calls to `Read` until the buffer has been filled.

Answer (score 2):

A stream is just a sequence of bytes. There is no concept of blocks except that which you create. You will need to invent some *additional* mechanism to understand where each block starts / ends. There are multiple common ways of doing this:

- using some "header" value, that (for example) indicates the number of bytes in the next block; for example you might use a fixed 32 bit integer counter and store [0 0 0 1 65 0 0 0 2 66 67] where the 0 0 0 1 is big-endian `1` meaning ""1 byte to read", and the 65 is the `A`, etc.
- sentinel values; for example, since this is a text protocol, you could perhaps end each block with either a nil value (0) or a line-feed; so [65 0 66 67 0] or [65 10 66 67 10]